# BizTalk 2020 - editing elements within a Mass Copy functoid

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2020

Is it possible to manipulate the copied elements within a Mass Copy functoid (or is there a design pattern that can be used instead)?

Currently, I call a REST endpoint to return user details. The user details contains an element that can contain many or none records (contact details, some users have email, some have email and telephone, some have none etc).

I then need to send that received payload back in the exact same structure, but I need to be able to edit some of the values with updated data.

Example;

User A has 2 contact points, and she has a new telephone number and email so I need to update these
User B has 1 contact point, just email, and he has a new email, so I need to update that

Mass Copy only allows a single input and output, so I can clone the original received REST payload 0- but is there a way to manipulate the values as part of that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing the map in on Orchestration, in the construct shape, you could have and Assignment shape after the map that you could use to update the distinguished property after the map.

If not using an Orchestration, then you might want to just consider a standard mapping approach that doesn't use the mass copy.